# Is there a way to get bacon crispy if you wrap it around potatoes and stick it in the oven?

Tags: baking, bacon

I wanted to try and make the “Gotcha Pork” dish from anime series Food Wars. It requires you wrap bacon around mashed potatoes and put it in the oven. Is there a way to bake it so the bacon comes out crispy? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The bacon should naturally come out crispy, as the oven cooks the bacon more evenly and the heat surrounds it. You can find [here](https://downshiftology.com/recipes/how-to-cook-bacon-in-the-oven/) an article that lists a couple of advantages of cooking bacon in the oven including extra crispiness.

I think the trick with dishes like “Gotcha Pork” is, to make sure you refrigerate or chill the dish, especially your mash before putting it in the oven. As the bacon will need around 20-40 min to get brown and crispy when it's wrapped around the potatoes (depending on the thickness of the bacon slices). You want to make sure, that the mashed potatoes don't run away but the bacon has got enough time to get brown and crispy.

Also to consider is that thicker bacon will take longer to fully cook and crisp up in the oven. My own experience is, when cooking bacon-wrapped chicken for example, that regular-cut bacon cooks the best (doesn't get burned too quickly but also gets fully crispy).

By googling it, I found a couple of recipes inspired by “Gotcha Pork”, that include instructions regarding refrigerating, etc. I personally found [this](https://www.bingingwithbabish.com/recipes/gotcha-pork-roast-food-wars) one very straightforward but would still take regular instead of thick bacon cut.